# Google Maps v3 wrong positioning

Tags: django, api, google-maps, django-templates

I'm doing an application in Django that has a small map in the user profile (provided by django-profile, but modified to use GMaps v3)

The thing is that any coordinate I put in the constructor it's represented wrong in the map. Currently I'm putting the coordinates of Santiago de Compostela (spain) at Lat. 42.88 and Long. -8.55 but Google maps keeps telling me that I'm in Bayingolin (China).

Bythe way, the same happens with Google Maps v2, it locates the coordinates wrong.

Here's the code:

```
{% block content %}
    {% if GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY and user.get_profile.location %}
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( {{ user.get_profile.latitude }}, {{ user.get_profile.longitude }} );
            var opts = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("location"), opts);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Test"
            });
        }
    </script>
    {% endif %}
<div id="profile">
<div id="profile_right">
    <div id="avatar" class="span-3 center">
        <a href="{% url profile_edit_avatar %}">
            <img class="border" src="/static/generic.96.jpg" />
        </a>
        <p><a href="{{ request.path_info }}edit/avatar/">{% if user.get_profile.has_avatar %}{% trans "Change avatar" %}{% else %}{% trans "Add avatar" %}{% endif %}</a></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>{% trans "Username: " %} {{ user }}</p>
        <p>{% trans "Real name: " %} {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
        <p>{% trans "Age: " %} {{ user. }}
        <p>{% trans "Member for: " %} {{ user.date_joined }}</p>
        <p>{% trans "E-mail:" %}
            <span class="{% if not email or not validated %}quiet red{% endif %}">
            {%if not email %}
                {% trans "Not set yet" %}
            {% else %}
                {{ email }}
                {% if not validated %}
                    {% trans " (Not validated)" %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="location">{% trans "Country" %}:</label>
        {% if user.get_profile.country %}
            {{ user.get_profile.get_country_display }}
        {% else %}
            <span class="quiet red">{% trans "Not set" %}</span>
        {% endif %}
        </p>

        <p>
            {% trans "Ciudad: " %} {{ user.get_profile.province }}
        </p>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="profile_left">
    {% if GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY %}
        <p>{% trans "Location" %}:
            {% if user.get_profile.location %}
                {{ user.get_profile.location }}
            {% else %}
                {% trans "Not set" %}
            {% endif %}
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.get_profile.location %}
        <div class="span-12 last">
            <div id="location" style="width: 480px; height: 240px;"></div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot with the result:
[image]

Comment: Added a screenshot with the template rendering :)

Comment: The interesting part is javascript/html ;)

Comment: @Mike: That's everything I have (related to Google maps). There's nothing more

Comment: The source of the page you made the screenshot of is the interesting part. Django templates are rendered to html and the html is rendered by browser. The result of the first 'rendered' is necessary in order to debug this issue.

Comment: @Mike: You were right. I read the rendered HTML and the problem was the I10N engine, it rendered the decimal point as a comma (in spain is noted with commas instead of points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I had the same problem that the I10N engine reformatted my decimal output. A workaround for me was to use the `stringformat:"s"` filter for outputting decimal numbers in the Javascript part of the templates.

In your case that would be:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( {{ user.get_profile.latitude|stringformat:"s" }}, {{ user.get_profile.longitude|stringformat:"s" }} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the coordinates for that place is 86.87110, 42.10547, which (in text) is pretty close to the coordinates you use, mayby some error in a parsing?

-8.55 --> 85.5 somehow?

Comment: I'm using DecimalField to store the coordinates, so it should't misplace the decimal point or negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem is the I10N engine of Django. I have it configured to Spanish units, and in spain, decimals are noted by a comma, not a point, so the result of storing for example: 42.1231 and -8.2456 ends up in: 42,1231 and -8,2456.

With my template, the ending result is:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42,1231,-8,2456);
```

That obviously cannot be parsed by Google Maps.